# Ruby - return false unless a value is true in which case return the value

Tags: ruby, return, conditional-statements

If `a = false` and `b = 2` is there a concise way to accomplish this? Using just `return a unless b` returns 'nil' instead of '2'.

I have

```
def checkit
  return a unless b
  b
end
```

Will this statement call b twice?

A real life case for this is:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= authenticate_user
end

def authenticate_user
    head :unauthorized unless authenticate_from_cookie 
end

def authenticate_from_cookie
  .
  if user && secure_compare(user.cookie, cookie)
    return user
  else
    return nil
  end
end
```

Comment: code and statement contradicts for me.. :( Where you wrote *If `a = false` and `b = 2`* in your code ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 ( b == true ) ? a : false
```

where a is a value you need to return

Answer (score 2):

I do not know why you have `false` stored in the variable `a`, so I omitted that. As I understand, you want to pass a value to the method `checkit`, which should return the value if its boolean value is `true` (which means everything except values `nil` and `false`), and otherwise return the value. In that case, just use this:

```
def checkit(value)
  value || false
end

checkit(1)       # => 1
checkit(false)   # => false
checkit('value') # => "value"
checkit(nil)     # => false
```